# Large volumes of remote obects

Tags: java, rmi

I am thinking of making an app with RMI, but I am not sure about the limitations of it.

The idea is, the client obtains a stub through the registry, then calls a remote method on that stub to obtain an `Authenticator` object. It has a method to log in after receiving a username and an encrypted password, which returns a `User` object, of which there is one for each user in the system. The user object has methods, that all return stub objects. The point is, there could conceivably be hundreds of thousands of remote objects all functioning at once. Can RMI handle all these objects, and how can I configure it so all objects are accessed on a single server port?

Comment: If you have enough RAM to waste, RMI won't complain. Each object is configured with its port, so just use the same port every time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Are RMI objects that are not being used garbage collected to save space?

Comment: Yes, except for those which are bound into the Registry, which will not be a problem in your case.

Comment: Like I said, there's only one object bound to the registry. Not a problem.

Comment: Do however keep in mind that using any remoting technology based on Java Serialization brings in many pitfalls and creats a very tight coupling between your client and server. If you don't pay meticulous attention in the design, you can soon end up with the complete server JAR as a client-side dependency. The amount of extra boilerplate to keep things under control usualy annuls any supposed benefits of the "transparency" of the distributed objects scheme.

Comment: I had a large-scale RMI deployment about ten years ago where there were fifty thousand remote objects. It scales well in this direction. @MarkoTopolnik Only remote objects that can be both DGC'd and locally GC'd will be garbage-collected. Being bound to the Registry is a sufficient but not necessary condition for that.

Comment: @EJP Quite so, I assume OP is aware of the consequence of objects remaining strongly reachable (I think he implied that with "not being used").

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well that's what he's asking about, and the answer you gave him isn't correct.